# intuitionistic logic - independence of premise

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

As part of preparing for a test, I wanted to go through how to tell if a inference is valid/not valid by intuitionistical logic. Given the following inference:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\forall x Fx \to \exists x Gx \\
\hline
\exists x (Fx \to Gx)
\end{array}$$

This inference is valid by classic logic, but I fail to see where this inference fails intuitionistically. Perhaps that for the conclusion that we would need a proof for some numeral $n$ that $Fn$ leads to $(Fx => Gx)$. But the premise doesn't give us such material?

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: Why did you remove the formula from the question? WIthout it, the question makes no sense!

Comment: @CarlMummert My bad sorry, I was in the process of cleaning another question and accidentally removed it

Answer (score 0):

This is closely related of the principle known as [independence of premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_of_premise). The Wikipedia article gives two heuristic arguments why that principle is not constructively valid. I will sketch them here, in the context of this principle, which is very close but not quite the same.

The first argument is based on the BHK interpretation. To prove the bottom formula, you would need to provide a specific $x$ so that, if $Fx$ holds then $Gx$ holds. To prove the top formula, you only need to provide a method that, given a proof of $\forall x Fx$, produces a proof of $\exists x Gx$.  There is no obvious way to take a method of that kind and use it to produce a specific value of $x$, which makes us suspicious of the constructive validity of the deduction.

The second argument is based on a weak counterexample. Let $Gx$ be such that we do not know whether there is any $x_0$ such that $Gx_0$. For example, $G$ could say that $x$ is a counterexample to Goldbach's conjecture. Let $Fx$ be the formula $\exists z Gz$, so $\forall x Fx$ is $\forall x \exists z Gz$. Then the implication $\forall x \exists z Gz \to \exists x Gx$ is trivial to prove constructively, but $\exists x ( \exists z Gz \to Gx)$ cannot be proved constructively unless we can produce an $x$ such that, if there is any counterexample to Goldbach's conjecture then $x$ is such a counterexample.  No such value of $x$ is known at the present time.

This weak counterexample can be used to prove more formally that the deduction from the question is not provable in various formal systems of constructive logic. The counterexample shows that, if we work in the language of arithmetic, and we assume the deduction rule from the question, then whenever $Hx$ is a decidable property of natural numbers we would have a way to determine whether $\exists x Hx$ is true. This would contradict the unsolvability of the Halting problem, among other things.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Based on this, I wanted to try to construct a solution: Suppose that $\forall x Fx \to \exists x Gx$. Now we suppose we can prove that $\exists x Fx$. Then there is some $n$ where $Fn$ is true but there is no obvious way to construct an operation/method to produce the specific value of $n$ such that $Gn$. The main problem is that the premise as there is no clear way to produce a specific value of x such that $Gx$?